# Normal distribution, $S^2$ distribution, and chi-square distribution exercise

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,\dots , X_{16}$ be a random sample from a normal population with mean  $\mu= 6$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 4$.

(a) What is the approximate distribution of X?

(b) Find $P( X< 4)$

(c) Find $P(S^2 < 4)$

Here is what I came up with:

(a) $\bar{X} \sim N(6, \frac{4}{16})$

(b) $P(\bar{X} <4) = P(Z < \frac{4-6}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{16}}})=P(Z<-4)=pnorm(-4)= 3.167124e-05$ Which I think is too small.

(c) Using theorem $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim X^2(n-1)$ I get

$P(S^2 < 4)= P(\frac{(16-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}< 4(16-1))= P(X<60) = pchisq(60, 15)= .999997$

For $b$ and $c$ the values are total opposites which make me think I'm not doing it correctly.

Comment: What is   $X$????

Comment: $X \sim X^2_{15}$

Comment: @Joz Was my answer helpful to you?

Comment: @Cristopher, yes thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) and (b) are correct. By the way, the probability you got in (b) isn't actually too small. Think about it this way, $\mu$ is $6$ so the probability that the sample mean ($\bar{X}$) is less than $-4$ will be really small.

(c) You forgot to divide by $\sigma^2$ on the right hand side of the inequality:

$P(S^2<4)=P(X<\dfrac{4(16-1)}{4})=P(X<15)$, where $X\sim\chi_{15}^2$.